# Explain the chest trap glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have seen a video about the chest trap glitch. It shows you that under an open chest, you cannot do any actions besides movement. It restricts you to left click or right click (right clicking opens the chest above you) and only allows you to move.

Is there any possible explanation for this glitch?
I am just trying to find out how to bypass this glitch, if not see why.
(It's very abusive in Hypixel.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a glitch, in fact it's a mistake by hypixel. This is beacuse the text you see(timers or anything else "floating") is actually an armorstand summoned via this command(1.13):`/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"\"some text\"",Invisible:1b}`. The problem is that it isn't a marker(which means that you can actually select a block behind it) entity. You can't get around it if you don't have the abilty to merge to it's data to `{Marker:1b}`.

Comment: Can't they just summon a smaller entity?

Comment: They could, but I don't know why they don't do it.